# How do I execute MongoDB shell query using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know we have various packages avalable on GitHub to query MongoDB using NodeJS. They don't solve my use case. I am looking to execute MongoDB Shell commands from NodeJS which are different from MongoDB NodeJS commands

Example: NodeJS

```
db.collection('user').find({})
```

Example: MongoDB Shell

```
db.getCollection('user').find({})
```

Notice 'collection' and 'getCollection' are different.

I want to save MongoDB Shell queries as text. How do I execute those queries once I have read them from the database?

Comment: _Example: MongoDB Shell: db.getCollection('user').find({})_ You can run mongo shell command within a sub-process in a node program.

Comment: For running using sub-process, I would need mongo installed on that system. It is a client application and installing mongo would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this adapted from the MongoDB documentation:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
// Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<cluster-url>?w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db("myDatabase");
    const result = await db.getCollection('user').find({});
    console.log(result);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Comment: I want to run this query from NodeJS, is this possible without using the mongo command as mongo db is not installed on the server running NodeJS.

Comment: @delsanic I have updated my answer to more specifically answer your question.

Comment: I am getting this error (node:16367) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.getCollection is not a function. 

db.collection works, but that's the issue, I want to store the queries as text and then execute them later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use child_process library of NodeJs but it is litte bit tricky. You must wait for mongo shell to finish its words.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const child = spawn("/usr/bin/mongo");

setTimeout(() => {
  child.stdin.write("show dbs\n");
}, 5000);

child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`command line says:\n${data}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try this code -

```
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 
 `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD}@
 ${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net`;

async function connectDatabase() {
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const db = client.db("main");

return {
listings: db.collection("test_listings")
   };
};

module.exports = { connectDatabase };
```